# How to merge master containing reverted commits to branch

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution, git-revert

I have master branch with initial state:

```
touch file
git add file
git commit -m "initial"
```

Then I did some changes:

```
echo "123" >> file
git commit -am "feature1"
```

which really belong to a feature branch, so I branched:

```
git branch TEST
```

and reverted change in master (I don't know if this is the best way to do it but it did what needed at the time):

```
git revert <last commit hash>
```

Then I did some more changes on feature branch:

```
git checkout TEST
echo "456" >> file
git commit -am "feature 1 continued"
```

And now I have problem merging master to it. What I want is to be able to merge all future changes in master to a TEST branch and keep my feature branch changes.

Code is already pushed to a remote.

Comment: who uses this remote - just you?

Comment: i am not sure i get what you are asking? maybe rebasing TEST over master? that would be the normal workflow of a feature branch which needs to be kept updated on the mainstream development

Comment: @guido if I rebase I get a conflict. Is there a way to skip revert commit from master? (I'm a git newbie)

Comment: did you push the wrong commit before the revert?

Comment: @guido unfortunatelly, yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Revert the revert

To be able to merge the `TEST` branch you'll need to revert the revert, so that the `TEST` history can be applied cleanly.

I.e. whereas originally the master branch history was:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git log --oneline
yyyyyyy Revert "wanted change"
xxxxxxx wanted change
....
```

And the `TEST` branch history is:

```
$ git checkout TEST
$ git log --oneline
aaaaaaa Test development commits
xxxxxxx wanted change
....
```

What you'll need is to achieve this:

```
$ git checkout TEST
$ git log --oneline
aaaaaaa Test development commits
zzzzzzz Revert "Revert "wanted change"" # <-
yyyyyyy Revert "wanted change"
xxxxxxx wanted change
....
```

I.e. a checkout at `xxxxxxx` and at `zzzzzzz` would be exactly the same.

### Use an intermediary branch

To do that, a relatively easy way is to use an intermediary branch:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git checkout -b merge-resolution
$ git revert yyyyyyy
$ git merge TEST
```

And then merge that branch with master:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge merge-resolution
$ git branch -d merge-resolution
```

This should result in a clean/consistent history in master, with the changes of `TEST` cleanly applied.

Comment: Shouldn't there be 'git checkout merge-resolution' after 'git branch merge-resolution'? (Or 'git checkout -b merge-resolution' instead?)